# which jdk i should install for intel i5 cpu and windows 7 64 bit

Tags: java

I have a i5 CPU and my os is windows 7 64 bit.Which jdk i shoul install? 
I  think its jdk-6u25-windows-x64.exe found at
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads

Comment: Yup, that should work............

Comment: Note that this type of question belongs to superuser.com rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Xr: For the JDK, it's fine here. For the JRE, it would definitely be superuser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the 64bit JDK and it is probably the best one for you. The 32bit version would also work. The opposite is not true; 32bit computers can only use 32bit JDKs, not the 64bit ones.

Comment: The 32 bit version has the advantage of being more memory efficient for programs which do not need many gigabytes of memory.

Answer (score 1):

Either the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version will work. The best choice depends on what you're developing. The main difference is that the JVM's internal pointers are twice as wide in the 64-bit version. Since the JVM internally represents reference values as pointers, any object on the heap containing references to other objects (which they all do) will take up more memory in the 64-bit version.  There's also extra padding to align them to 8-byte boundaries. However the 64-bit version can address a larger amount of memory.